# How to dynamically add's collections within collections in Symfony2 form types

Tags: collections, symfony

I have 3 form types in symfony2

FaultType which is the parent of all next collections

```
<?php

namespace My\FaultBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class FaultType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    { 
        $builder
                ->add('title')
                ->add('steps', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new StepType(),
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'prototype' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                ))
                ->add('created')
                ->add('updated')
        ;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'My\FaultBundle\Entity\Fault'
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_fault_fault';
    }

}
```

StepType:

```
<?php

namespace My\FaultBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class StepType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('body')
            ->add('photos', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new PhotoType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'My\FaultBundle\Entity\Step'
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_fault_step';
    }
}
```

and the last PhotoType:

```
<?php

namespace My\FaultBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class PhotoType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('filename')
        ;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'My\FaultBundle\Entity\Photo'
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_fault_photo';
    }
}
```

I found excelent article [link](http://toni.uebernickel.info/2012/03/15/an-example-of-symfony2-collectiontype-form-field-prototype.html) about prototype, and with one nested form type is very good, but I have a problem when a want to get this to work with third nest mean PhotoType... Photos are in collection of Steps, which is collection of Fault..., how can I achive dynamically add/remove photos for steps with this example...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a JS snippet that can be of help here. you just have to add two buttons [add new, delete last].
https://gist.github.com/juanmf/10483041

it can handle recursive/nested prototypes.
It's coupled with a mediator (same as Symfony event Dispatcher) that allows you to bind generated controls to events. If you dont need the mediator delete these lines:

```
docdigital.mediatorInstance.send(
    docdigital.constants.mediator.messages.clonePrototype_prototypeAdded,
    $clone
);
```

Comment: Please consider adding the relevant content you've linked into your answer. See: [**Provide context for links**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make you own prototype.

There are 2 solutions:

1. Find with regex all digit segments of a `property_path`, and replace them with placeholder

   ```
   $segments_found = preg_match('/\[(\d+)\]/', $prototype, $matches);
   ```
2. Use recursion to find top collection parent and build path manually from there.

Did you try reordering items? This is total disaster;)